# How to handle error while returning an observable in angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, error-handling, observable

I am creating an `AuthGuard` for my app..now when i try to load the component without getting **logged in** it should redirect me to the login page..But i am getting an error like following
[image: image error]

and nothing happens.

I am throwing this error from my backend `{"status":401,"message":"Auth Token Not found!"}}`
as there is no auth token

The following is the code of my `AuthGuard`

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> {

    return this.authService.checkLogin().pipe(
      map((data: HttpResponse) => {
        if (data.status == 200) {
          console.log("OUTPUT:", data)
          return true
        }
        else return false
      }),
    )

  }
}
```

The following is my function in `AuthService`:

```
 public checkLogin():Observable<HttpResponse> {

    return this.http.get<HttpResponse>('http://localhost:5000/auth/check-login', { withCredentials: true })

  }
```

Now how can i handle the errors like these and set a fallback value to `false` so if any error occurs then that route could not be accessed

Comment: Where is the code that should redirect the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to achieve the following behavior:

- If `checkLogin()` gets a response that indicates "success", the auth-guard shall return `true`
- If `checkLogin()` gets an error-response, redirect the user to a fallback-page and return `false`

If you use the code below, please note that `catchError()` is only triggered if the backend responds with an exception, while `map()` is always triggered if a success-response comes in from the backend.
Therefore, in the positive case, you can simply return `true` without checking the contents of the response. However, if you receive an exception from the backend, you can redirect the user to the fallback page using `this.router.navigate()` and then return `of(false)` to prevent the request from passing the auth guard.

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> {

    return this.authService.checkLogin().pipe(
      map(() => true),
      catchError(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['route-to-fallback-page']);
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Alternative solution for Angular 7.1+**

Starting from Angular 7.1 you can just return a `UrlTree`-Object containing the fallback-route:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {

    return this.authService.checkLogin().pipe(
      map(() => true),
      catchError(() => this.router.parseUrl('/route-to-fallback-page'))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use shared error response

```
this.http.get<HttpResponse>('http://localhost:5000/auth/check-login', { withCredentials: true }).pipe(
          catchError((error=>{
           
            this.getErrorMessage(error);
           return throwError(()=>error);
          }))
        )
```

The getErrorMessage Function will return the errors;

```
 private getErrorMessage(error:HttpErrorResponse){
   
      switch(error.status){
        
        case 400:{
          return this.toast.error(`Bad Request :${JSON.stringify(error.error?.Message)}`,error.status.toString())
        }
        case 401:{
          return this.toast.error(`Unauthorized :${JSON.stringify(error.error?.Message)}`,error.status.toString())
        }
        case 403:{
          return this.toast.error(`Access Denied :${JSON.stringify(error.error?.Message)}`,error.status.toString())
        }
        case 500:{
          return this.toast.error(`Internal Server Error :${JSON.stringify(error.error?.Message)}`,error.status.toString())
        }
        case 404:{
          return this.toast.error(`Page Not Found :${JSON.stringify(error.error?.Message)}`,error.status.toString())
        }
       default:{
        return this.toast.error('Check your internet connection!');
       }
      }
    }
```